# Why :hasbounty search option was never implemented?

Tags: discussion, bounties, search

I found multiple questions about this within several last year:

[How to search only unanswered questions with an open bounty ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144952/how-to-search-only-unanswered-questions-with-an-open-bounty)

[How can I search for bounty questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54476/how-can-i-search-for-bounty-questions/54477#54477)

[List previously featured questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108696/list-previously-featured-questions)

[Advanced search criteria for bounty questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68253/advanced-search-criteria-for-bounty-questions)

[Advanced search option to include questions with bounty among the search criteria and other cool search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71079/advanced-search-option-to-include-questions-with-bounty-among-the-search-criteri)

[Can we get some better bounty hunting tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130252/can-we-get-some-better-bounty-hunting-tools)

Most of answers boiled down to two ideas:

- Use hasnotice:1 answers:0 closed:0. It's imperfect, but what can we do...
- Go and browse featured manually or with limited filtering options

Why it was never implemented? It sounds like reasonably straightforward thing (and without any obvious downsides)

*Update 1*

I was under impression that a lot of feature prioritization is driven by community.  It looks like people interested in it. I didn't see anybody opposing it, but it wasn't implemented within last 3 years. That's the main reason for my question.

Comment: To answer your question: because the devs never implemented it. I don't really see what this question does other than link all the related questions in one place.

Comment: @animuson: I updated my question to explain my reasons to ask it.

Comment: If you search within a specific tag ([tagname]) there will be a tab for bounties questions.  Not exactly what you want, but close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Community voting does play a part on what developers decide to implement on the site, but so do many other things. If the developers truly feel the feature is not worthwhile or helpful in any way, they do have the ability to completely ignore it.

Ultimately, if the question isn't tagged with a red-status-tag, the developers haven't yet made any official decision on it. There are a *lot* of features out there ([over 10,000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status*)) that haven't been marked by the SE team, many with a lot more support than these bounty search features.

So to answer your question: they just haven't implemented it yet. All you can do is continue supporting it and adding bounties if you really want it to get a lot of attention.

Comment: Whoa.... I didnt realize that so many features were requested. Now it makes more sense